# Create dummies for followup visits

Tags: r, panel

I have a simple data structure with id and time-series indicator (prd). I would like to create a dummy variable for followup visits "fup", which is equal to 0 if a patient has no more visits and 1 if a patient has more visits in the future.

How would I go about doing this?

```r
id<- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3)
prd <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2)

df <- data.frame(id=id, prd=prd)
```

Desired output:

```r
  id prd fup
1  1   1   1
2  1   2   1
3  1   3   0
4  2   1   0
5  3   1   1
6  3   2   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can check if the current row is the last row in each group. In base R,

```
df$fup <- with(df, ave(prd, id, FUN = function(x) seq_along(x) != length(x)))
df

#  id prd fup
#1  1   1   1
#2  1   2   1
#3  1   3   0
#4  2   1   0
#5  3   1   1
#6  3   2   0
```

Similarly in `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  group_by(id) %>%  mutate(fup = +(row_number() != n()))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, fup := +(seq_along(prd) != .N), by = id]
```

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for.